# How to stop execution on uncaught type error javascript in ExtJS 4.1.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm getting uncaught type error in one of the supporting class where I'm parsing through the data. However application doesn't stop in case of error.

Is there any way I can suspend the execution when first type error happens to investigate details for it.

I tried something this like but no luck
    if(data === 'undefined'){
      debugger;
    }

Comment: Use `ext-all-debug.js` instead of `ext-all.js` as ext core JS file. It's gona show you debug information.

Comment: Show an example where you are expecting to catch exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by s.webbandit using Ext-Js-Debug version is pretty helpful once you able to find the location of error to trace the details.

Few ways to stop/suspend execution when execution happens

1. Use chrome to run the app and click button which available at bottom under Source tab to pause on uncaught exception
2. Add try/catch exception handling block in your code and get the stacktrace or add debugger in catch block to inspect details.
3. Directly put the debugger dynamically while code is executing

I'm sure there might more elegant ways to do this. However, I'm able to solve my issue using first way.